# Update values in multiple large JSON files

Tags: json, node.js, stream, gulp

I have a folder with several large JSON files and would like to optimize them. I was using `gulp` with `gulp-replace` to remove white space.

The files contain a large JSON object where under some sub-property I would like to update some values. Since the files are large, I was looking into JSON streaming to keep the memory footprint low. There are several JSON streaming libraries like [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream), [BFJ](https://github.com/philbooth/bfj), [Oboe](https://github.com/philbooth/bfj) and [stream-json](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json) available.

`JSONStream` seemed the easiest one to use, as it allowed path matching with placeholders but the matched value seems to be only for extracting data and not for updating.

So what I'd like to achieve is streaming data in, parsing some specific sub-object, update its values, stringify that sub-object again and save the whole data with updated values back on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using `JSONStream`. The recently added feature of emitting the `header` and `footer` events to get the date before and after the matched that I was interested in came in handy.

```
var es = require('event-stream');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var isFirst = false;
var isHeader = false;

fs.createReadStream('filename.geojson')
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse(['features', true], function(data) {
    // map the data
    return data;
  }))
  .on('header', function(data) {
    // push the part before the first match
    this.push(data);
  })
  .pipe(es.through(function write(data) {

    if(isHeader === false) {
      let dataStr = JSON.stringify(data);
      // recreate the original structure
      dataStr = dataStr.substring(0, dataStr.length - 1) +
                ',"features":[\n';
      isHeader = true;

      this.emit('data', dataStr);
    } else {
      // stringify the data and add a comma to each of the 
      // matched lines except the first one
      let dataStr = (isFirst === true ? ',' : '') +
                    JSON.stringify(data) + '\n';
      isFirst = true;

      this.emit('data', dataStr);
    }
  }, function end() {
    // properly close the json
    this.emit('data', ']}');
    this.emit('end');
  }))
  // store the json
;
```